# Sum JSON properties across multiple rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table with two columns: `id` and `values`. The `values` column is a json array that has `n` number of elements, each is a json object. The json object has two properties `a` and `b`, both of which are floats. I'm trying to write a query that sums up the `a` property at the first index of the json array at `values` across all rows. Then it does the same thing for propery `b`. Additionally, it should do that for all json objects at all indices. Is that possible? I know that you can manipulate and query json columns in SQL Server (that's what I'm using), but couldn't figure something out to achieve this.

**Example**

Here's an example that illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. Assume we have the following rows:

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 4}]` |
| 2 | `[{"a": 3, "b": 6}, {"a": 4, "b": 8}]` |
| 3 | `[{"a": 5, "b": 10}, {"a": 6, "b": 12}]` |
| 4 | `[{"a": 7, "b": 14}, {"a": 8, "b": 16}]` |

The resulting query should give the following:

| aggregate |
| --- |
| `[{"a": 16, "b": 32}, {"a": 20, "b": 40}]` |

In the example above `n` is two since each `values` column has an array of length 2. The length (aka, `n`) is always guaranteed to be equal across all rows, but `n` can be any number not necessarily 2.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? And will there always be just `a` and `b` JSON properties? And what would the maximum number of objects in the array be?

Comment: @Charlieface SQL Server 2019. Yep, only `a` and `b`. The maximum number is 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break out separate `a` and `b` values, and rebuild the JSON afterwards.

If you had a fixed number of indices then you could easily use `JSON_VALUE(values, '$[0].a')` etc, but since you have any number of objects in the array, you need to shred the array into separate rows with `OPENJSON`

```sql
SELECT
    a = SUM(CAST(JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.a') AS int)),
    b = SUM(CAST(JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.b') AS int))
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.[values]) j   -- with no path then [key] is the array index, [value] is the object
GROUP BY CAST(j.[key] AS int)
ORDER BY CAST(j.[key] AS int)
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [JSON_VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as it's what is required here. The path will be either `'$[0].a'` or `'$[0].b'`.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92a7b/25) example the achieves what you're after.